# How can I export query SQL file in TeamSQL to local file

Tags: teamsql

TeamSQL is a good tool for collaboration, able to save Query to the cloud and share with other team members.
However I cannot find the option to export the SQL Query to local text file, anyone know if there's any trick to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamSQL keeps your queries on the cloud, it's not possible to export your queries to local file yet, but it can be available after 4.0 stable release (probably in 2 weeks, it'll be released). Currently it's in the beta.

Comment: thanks, seems 4.0 is not yet released, waiting for this feature :)